# How to access a KStreams Materialized State Store from another Stream Processor

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to be able to remove a record from a Ktable from a separate Stream Processor. Today I'm using aggregate() and passing a materialized state store. In a separate processor that reads from a "termination" topic, I'd like to query that materialized state store either in a .transform() or a different .aggregate() and 'remove' that key/value. Every time I try to access the materialized state from a separate stream processor, it keeps telling me either the store isn't added to the topology, so then I add it and run it again, then it tells me it's already be registered and errors out.

```
      builder.stream("topic1").map().groupByKey().aggregate(() -> null,
        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
          //add to the Ktable
          return newValue;
        },
        stateStoreMaterialized);
```

and in a separate stream I want to delete a key from that stateStoreMaterialized

```
builder.stream("topic2")
.transform(stateStoreDeleteTransformer, stateStoreSupplier.name())
```

stateStoreDeleteTransformer will query the key and delete it.

```
//in ctor
        KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier stateStoreSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("store1");
    stateStoreMaterialized = Materialized.<String, MyObj>as(stateStoreSupplier)
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
        .withValueSerde(mySerDe);
```

I don't have a terminal flag on my topic1 stream object value that can trigger a deletion. It has to come from another stream/topic.

When I try to use the same Materialized Store on two separate stream processors I get..

```
 Invalid topology: Topic STATE_STORE-repartition has already been registered by another source.
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.start(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.java:268)
```

Edit:

This is the 1st error I receive.

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Processor KSTREAM-TRANSFORMVALUES-0000000012 has no access to StateStore store1 as the store is not connected to the processor. If you add stores manually via '.addStateStore()' make sure to connect the added store to the processor by providing the processor name to '.addStateStore()' or connect them via '.connectProcessorAndStateStores()'. DSL users need to provide the store name to '.process()', '.transform()', or '.transformValues()' to connect the store to the corresponding operator. If you do not add stores manually, please file a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA.

at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.getStateStore(ProcessorContextImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ForwardingDisabledProcessorContext.getStateStore(ForwardingDisabledProcessorContext.java:85)

So then I do this:

```
stateStoreSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(STATE_STORE_NAME);
storeStoreBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(stateStoreSupplier, Serdes.String(), jsonSerDe);
stateStoreMaterialized = Materialized.as(stateStoreSupplier);
```

Then I get this error:

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore 'state-store' is already added.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.addStateStore(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:520)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.addStateStore(InternalTopologyBuilder.java:512)

---

Here's the code that fixed my issue. As it turns out, order matters when building the streams. Had to set the materialized store first and then in subsequent lines of code, setup the transformer.

```
  /**
   * Create the streams using the KStreams DSL - a method to configure the stream and add any state stores.
   */
  @Bean
  public KafkaStreamsConfig setup() {

    final JsonSerDe<Bus> ltaSerde = new JsonSerDe<>(Bus.class);
    final StudentSerde<Student> StudentSerde = new StudentSerde<>();
    //start lta stream
    KStream<String, Bus> ltaStream = builder
        .stream(ltaInputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), ltaSerde));

    final KStream<String, Student> statusStream = this.builder
        .stream(this.locoStatusInputTopic,
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
                StudentSerde));

    //create lta store
    KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier ltaStateStoreSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(LTA_STATE_STORE_NAME);

    final Materialized<String, Bus, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> ltaStateStoreMaterialized =
        Materialized.
            <String, Bus>as(ltaStateStoreSupplier)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(ltaSerde);

    KTable<String, Bus> ltaStateProcessor = ltaStream
        //map and convert lta stream into Loco / LTA key value pairs
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), ltaSerde))
        .aggregate(
            //The 'aggregate' and 'reduce' functions ignore messages with null values FYI.
            // so if the value after the groupbykey produces a null value, it won't be removed from the state store.
            //which is why it's very important to send a message with some terminal flag indicating this value should be removed from the store.
            () -> null, /* initializer */
            (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
              if (null != newValue.getAssociationEndTime()) { //if there is an endTime associated to this train/loco then remove it from the ktable
                logger.trace("removing LTA: {} loco from {} train", newValue.getLocoId(), newValue.getTrainAuthorization());
                return null; //Returning null removes the record from the state store as well as its changelog topic. re: https://objectpartners.com/2019/07/31/slimming-down-your-kafka-streams-data/
              }
              logger.trace("adding LTA: {} loco from {} train", newValue.getLocoId(), newValue.getTrainAuthorization());
              return newValue;
            }, /* adder */
            ltaStateStoreMaterialized
        );

    // don't need builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreStoreBuilder); and CANT use it
    // because the ltaStateStoreMaterialized will already be added to the topology in the KTable aggregate method above.
    // The below transformer can use the state store because it's already added (apparently) by the aggregate method.
    // Add the KTable processors first, then if there are any transformers that need to use the store, add them after the KTable aggregate method.


    statusStream.map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getLocoId(), v))
        .transform(locoStatusTransformerSupplier, ltaStateStoreSupplier.name())
        .to("testing.outputtopic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), StudentSerde));

    return this; //can return anything except for void.
  }
```

Comment: In theory you should be able to connect the state store from the KTable to a transformer -- note though that building the topology is "lazy" and thus it seems that the `KTable` store is added after you try to attach it to the transformer -- maybe you can change the order in which you make the corresponding calls to `StreamsBuilder`? Also, do you have topology optimization enabled (if yes, this might also change the order). -- Adding the state store manually won't work for this case.

Comment: I will try that and report back.. In the mean time, does deleting it directly from the state store (via a transform) also "delete" it (tombstone) from the KTable and changelog topic?

Comment: Yes, it would. A `KTable` is just a logical abstractions around the store and change logging is also part of the store itself.

Comment: I was able to access the store from a transform. It turns out, the streambuilder sequence of order matters. I moved my lines of code to create the KTable first with materialized store, then create the other stream processor that uses the transform to access the store. I didn't need to manually add the store to the builder.addStore(), the aggregate() did that behind the scenes.

Comment: As I suspected :) -- because the internal `KTable` state, well, is internal, accessing it from a different processor is actually a hack... That's why it's not really documented how to do it.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax it is sort of a hack but it has very similar semantics to a join..as it turns out, I’ve had many use cases over the past two years where I’ve needed to lookup something from a different processor’s internal state. We use it as a means to enrich a different message stream  but can’t use a join because we need more control over whats in  “internal changelog “ that a ktable join can provide.

Comment: Well, the DSL is build with a certain purpose/use-cases in mind. If it's not doing it's job for you, you need to fall back to the PAPI an build your own custom operators.

Answer (score 0):

1. is `stateStoreMaterialized` and `stateStoreSupplier.name()` has the same name?
2. Use have a error in your topology

```
KStream.transform(stateStoreDeleteTransformer, stateStoreSupplier.name())
```

You have to supply new instant of StateStoreDeleteTransformer per ProcessContext in TransformerSupplier, like this:

```
KStream.transform(StateStoreDeleteTransformer::new, stateStoreSupplier.name()) 
or
KStream.transform(() -> StateStoreDeleteTransformerSupplier.get(), stateStoreSupplier.name())//StateStoreDeleteTransformerSupplier return new instant of StateStoreDeleteTransformer
```

3. in `stateStoreDeleteTransformer` how do you intent on using `stateStoreMaterialized` inside transformer directly?
   I have the similar use case and I using a `KeyValueStore<String, MyObj>`

```
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        kvStore = (KeyValueStore<String, MyObj>) context.getStateStore("store1");
    }
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some more context. 1) yes they have the same name. 2) I fixed that. 3) I think the only way to use a state store is to use context.getStateStore - which I think doesn't return a Materialized store, but a KeyValueStore. I don't think the KStreams developers meant for the users to modify a Materialized state store outside of the aggregate() methods. So I don't think its possible to manage the internal state of a KTable and Materialized store inside of a transform operation. :(

I think I will forego using a Ktable join and use a transform approach as a synthetic join.

Comment: `KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier` is used to create the store and then'll be used to create a `StoreBuilder` to add to topology, can you share how you build the topology

Comment: btw `Materialized` is just used to described how you store the `StateStore`, then you can used `StateStore` using getStateStore in `Transformer` or `Processor`